# Wordpress Shortcode through Plugin does not function as intended (Elementor Pro)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, elementor

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/5fxqmb89/

As you can see in my JS Fiddle. everything works fine. However in my Wordpress plugin using Elementor Pro, the javascript is not working as intended:

[image]

**Issue:** the dropdown keeps on opening no matter how much it gets clicked. It closes in a split second then opens up again.

here is the exact code I am using inside my Wordpress Plugin:

```
function locationsfunction(){
    echo'<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css">
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>';
    global $wpdb;
?>

<div class="select-menu">
    <div class="location-btn">
      <span class="location-text">Location</span>
      <i class="bx bx-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
  
    <ul class="options">
      <li class="option">
        <span class="option-text">Florida</span>
      </li>
      <li class="option">
        <span class="option-text">Georgia</span>
      </li>
      <li class="option">
        <span class="option-text">Texas</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>';

<style> > see jsfiddle for the css </style>

<script>
    const optionMenu = document.querySelector('.select-menu'),
    location_btn = optionMenu.querySelector('.location-btn'),
    options = optionMenu.querySelectorAll('.option'),
    location_text = optionMenu.querySelector('.location-text');

    location_btn.addEventListener('click', () => optionMenu.classList.toggle('active'));

    options.forEach((option) => {
    option.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let selectedOption = option.querySelector('.option-text').innerText;
        location_text.innerText = selectedOption;

        optionMenu.classList.remove('active');
    });
        });
</script>

<?php
}
add_shortcode('locationsoutput','locationsfunction');
?>
```

I placed the html, script, and css inside my function for it's use in the shortcode

Also here is the Plugin name within wordpress:

[image]

Additionally here is the shortcode within Elementor Pro:

[image]

Here is what I tried:

- Repositioning the script/html/css where html is first inside the function so that the css and script reads it after
- one stack question suggested to turn the script " into '. (single quotation). This does not change anything in my end
- Put the <script> inside a function. Same issue with the dropdown above.

Need some advice on what to do. Hope I explained my issue clearly. Feel free to comment if any elaboration is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of mistakes in your code, I can't fix your whole code but I can give you a guide so that you can correct your code.

1. Shortcode's callback functions should only `return` the content, if You use `echo` it will create the problem.
2. css and js should be added/enqueued in WordPress using script and style enqueue functions [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) there are some other functions as well which you'll get to know after reading the documentation.
3. WordPress loads the `jquery.min.js` so you don't have to add another jquery. `jquery.slim` also doesn't require for your code to work.
4. `global $wpdb;` line is unnecessary, You're not using the `$wpdb` variable anywhere in your code. if you'll use it in the future then keep it.
5. I am not sure if your code requires bootstrap js/css and popper js or not, if not then it's better to remove those things as well.
6. add the prefix in your CSS class to avoid any conflicts with other CSS classes coming from core/theme/plugins, or use a container class and foreach the nodes and select the child node using the parent node.